# mobile browser shows correct info but desk top doesn't

Tags: html

I don't have much experience with code. My issue is when i open page on mobile devices it shows info correct but desktop doesn't. The issue i have a email address at the top off the page shows up (services) on mobile browser and shows up as (support) on desktop. both browsers use the same index.html.

```
<!-- Top Navbar -->

<div class="top_nav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="list-inline info">
      <li><a href="tel:443-875-8570"><span class="fa fa-phone"></span> (443)875-8570</a></li>
      <li><a href="mailto:services@myemail"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> Mon - Sat 9:00am - 6:00pm</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might be having some css which handles this.. some different set of styles will be applied for mobile page.

Comment: The problem is fixed. I believe i just needed to clear my history on my browser.

Comment: thank you for taking time to post an answer. Still not sure why clearing history would fix the issue.

Comment: The js/css might have been cached in browser, So when you seen such kind of issues in future refresh the page with `Ctrl+F5` instead of just `F5`.